# example sort two div's

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have two div's A and B, I looking example to switch between them without reloading a page, for example onclick a first button show only div A,  second button show only Div B, and third button show all A and B div's

Comment: You need to provide code of what you have tried already

Comment: have a look [here](https://google.com/)

Comment: What have you done so far? Your requirement is quite simple.

Comment: so far nothing, and I can't do coz I dont know well js, only can work with examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="A" style="dispay:none">
  <p> this is div 1 </p>
</div>
<div id="B" style="dispay:none">
  <p> this is div 2 </p>
</div>
<input type="button" value="showA" onclick="showA()">
<input type="button" value="showA" onclick="showB()">
<input type="button" value="showA" onclick="showAB()">
<script>
  var showA = function()
  {
   document.getElementById('A').style.display = 'block';
   document.getElementById('B').style.display = 'none'; 
  }
  var showB = function()
  {
   document.getElementById('B').style.display = 'block';
   document.getElementById('A').style.display = 'none'; 
  }
  var showAB = function()
  {
   document.getElementById('A').style.display = 'block';
   document.getElementById('B').style.display = 'block'; 
  }
</script>
```

Comment: hi, if I have more than 2 div's ,its script not sorting

Comment: if have more than two div's then you must be having more than two buttons, then add functions respectively like

<div id='c' style='display:none'></div>


then add an input button
<input type="button" value="showC" onclick="showC()">

then add function under script

var showC = function()
{ 
   document.getElementById('C').style.display = 'block';
 // and make remaining as display none
}

Comment: no, I mean , I have 10 div's with id="A", and 5 div's with id="B" and in this case not sorting

Comment: in this case you must read out first, id is applicable for  a single tag only as it uniquely identify that tag, if you are giving same id's to multiple tags then only first tag will take that id and rest will not.

In order to overcome this , you must use calss

read more at https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/